# How to assert something about every item in enumerable in a long LINQ chain

Tags: c#, linq, assert

Is there something like

```
myList.Select(..).Where(...).Assert(x=>x.Length<2).Select(...)...
```

which throws if any item does not satisfy the condition and which acts like `.Select(x=>x)` otherwise?

Comment: Would you want it to throw an exception for the first item that violates your constraint, or for every item?

Comment: @JonathanChase First item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write this extension pretty easily yourself. Assuming you have an exception in mind, say, `AssertionFailedException`, something like this would do the trick.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Assert<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> expression)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
          if(!expression(item))
                throw new AssertionFailedException();
          yield return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing built-in, but it's easy enough to write something:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Assert<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        if (input is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        if (condition is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(condition));

        return Impl();

        IEnumerable<T> Impl()
        {
            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                if (!condition(item))
                    throw new AssertionFailedException(...);
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, of course, this will only check items when the `IEnumerable<T>` that it returns is enumerated.

Comment: I'm not sure why I thought local functions couldn't be iterators, but it's good to see they can be.

Comment: what is the advantage of this (besides the null checking) over Jonathan's answer?

Comment: @Bananach Just the null-checking. We posted our answers at the same time.

Comment: @Bananach canton's solution here is a more diligent implementation, as the guard clauses are a smart thing to add to any extension like this. I was simply posting the meat of the implementation.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, @JonathonChase got there 20 seconds earlier, so feel free to accept their answer. I'll leave mine up for completeness)

Comment: I didn't mean the guard clauses. I meant the `return Impl()` instead of just running `Impl` like @JonathanChase did

Comment: You should not put argument validation inside a method which uses `yield return`: you should do your argument validation first, and then call a separate method which does `yield return`. This means that any exceptions are thrown as soon as the method is called, and not when the `IEnumerable` is first iterated.